# Sentence Capitalizer with specific requirement

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

It's hard to explain but I'm trying to create a program that only capitalizes the letter of every word that ends with a period, question mark, or exclamation point. I have managed to receive a result when inputting any of the marks but only when it is entered the second time. In other words I have to hit enter twice to get a result and I'm not sure why. I am still working on it on my own but I'm stuck at this problem.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SentenceCapitalizer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a sentence: ");
        String line = keyboard.nextLine();

        String wrong = keyboard.nextLine();
        String[] check = {".!?"};
        String upper_case_line="";
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);

        for (String sent : check)
        {
            if (sent.startsWith(wrong))
            {
                System.out.println("cant use .?!");
            }
            else
            {


             /* if (line.startsWith(" "))//if starts with space
                System.out.println("good");
            else
                System.out.println("bad");
            */

            //if (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++)
            //{char c = line.chartAt(i);
                while(lineScan.hasNext())
                {
                    String word = lineScan.next();
                    upper_case_line +=   Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) +
                            word.substring(1) + " ";
                }

                System.out.println(upper_case_line.trim());
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Hey just a quick solution for your question. Converts the string to character array and then checks the character array for '.!?' if it finds the value then it will make the next letter a capital!

```
public class SentenceCapitalizer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Scanner, Variable to hold ouput
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input a sentence: ");
    String line = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Char array, boolean to check for capital
    char [] lineChars = line.toCharArray();
    boolean needCapital = false;

    //String to hold output
    String output = "";

    //Check for period in line
    for (int i = 0; i < lineChars.length; i++) {

        //Make sure first char is upper case
        if (i == 0) {
            lineChars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(lineChars[i]);
        }

        //Check for uppercase if char is not space
        if (needCapital && Character.isLetter(lineChars[i])) {
            lineChars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(lineChars[i]);
            needCapital = false;
        }

        if (lineChars[i] == '.' || lineChars[i] == '?' || lineChars[i] == '!') {
            needCapital = true;
        }

        //Add character to string
        output += lineChars[i];
    }

    //Output string
    System.out.println (output);
}
}
```

Comment: @SirNicholas No problem! Glad to help!